# Every text on screen disappears after restarting flutter release app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I have a custom font Berlin-Sans set in my app and don't use the default Flutter font, but for some reason, when I open the release version of my apk for the first time, all the text displays correctly, but when I close the app and open it again, all the text are gone

[image]

I have even tried setting the default font in theme settings like this:

```dart
static final _baseTheme = ThemeData(fontFamily: AppFonts.berlinSansFB);
```

Comment: post a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do that